# Failed to initialize Git team provider

Tags: android, eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, egit

whenever I add an `Android project` to a `git repository`  using the eclipse plugin `EGit` I get this Error message

> Failed to initialize Git team provider.

when visualising the error log I get this :

```
Failed to initialize Git team provider. 
Problems encountered while moving resources.
Could not move '/SearchInContatsWithLoader'.
Could not move: D:\AndrComp\SearchInContatsWithLoader.
Problems encountered while deleting files.
Could not delete: D:\AndrComp\SearchInContatsWithLoader\libs\android-support-v4.jar.
Could not delete: D:\AndrComp\SearchInContatsWithLoader\libs.
Could not delete: D:\AndrComp\SearchInContatsWithLoader.
```

Comment: Probably permissions problems. Try manually deleting those files for egit.

Comment: why git would delete that file ?! normaly it should place it in the repository !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you don't have a windows process blocking those file (keeping an handle on them), which would prevent another process (like `EGit`) to move them.

To solve the issue, try to close as many processes as you can (or, even better, reboot and launch just Eclipse), and try again your operation.

Comment: the problem is always with `android-support-v4.jar` could it be the adb process that is keeping a handle on that file while EGit is working ?

Comment: @zizoujab could you try and copy your project elsewhere, and then try the import from that new place?

Comment: @zizoujab strange, and if you remove that `android-support-v4.jar` from your copy before trying to import, same result?

Comment: @zizoujab so you could remove it, and then add it directly in the git repo created by the import in Eclipse. However, that seems cumbersome...